# Extend django.core.paginator Paginator to work with Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, paginator

How would one extend the [`Paginator`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator) class in [`django.core.paginator`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/paginator.py) to work with Google App Engine [`queries`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes are necessary:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, Page

class GAEPaginator(Paginator):
    def page(self, number):
      "Returns a Page object for the given 1-based page number."
      number = self.validate_number(number)
      offset = (number - 1) * self.per_page
      if offset+self.per_page + self.orphans >= self.count:
        top = self.count
      return Page(self.object_list.fetch(self.per_page, offset), number, self)
```

It would be nice of Paginator was aware of GAE cursors.

Please feel free to edit this answer with improvements.